# Monodroid not running on Jelly Bean 4.1.1

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

Direct to the point: My Galaxy Nexus come with ICS (4.0.4) installed and it was fun. Last week come the JB (4.1.1) and was very fun.

The problem is that not even a blank (that one that come just with a button to count clicks) project with Mono For Android 4.2.4 run on it.

The output:
Packaging application..
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.269]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/21/2012 4:10:07 PM.
Project "C:\Trabalho\Temp\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj" on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).
_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
  MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\
  MonoAndroid Framework: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\
  MonoAndroid Binaries: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\
  Android SDK: C:\Android\android-sdk\
  Java SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\
_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
  GetAndroidPackageName Task
    ManifestFile: 
    AssemblyName: AndroidApplication1
    PackageName: AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1
_ExtractLibraryProjectImports:
    Assemblies: 
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
_UpdateAndroidResgen:
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  AndroidApplication1 -> C:\Trabalho\Temp\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\AndroidApplication1.dll
_ConvertDebuggingFiles:
Skipping target "_ConvertDebuggingFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_ResolveAssemblies:
  ResolveAssemblies Task
    ReferenceAssembliesDirectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\;;
    I18nAssemblies: 
    LinkMode: None
    Assemblies:
      bin\Debug\AndroidApplication1.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    [Output] ResolvedAssemblies:
      C:\Trabalho\Temp\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\AndroidApplication1.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Security.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
    [Output] ResolvedUserAssemblies:
      C:\Trabalho\Temp\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\AndroidApplication1.dll
    [Output] ResolvedFrameworkAssemblies:
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.0.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Security.dll
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
_GenerateJavaStubs:
Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_AddStaticResources:
  Resource obj\Debug\android\assets\machine.config is unchanged. Skipping.
  Resource obj\Debug\android\src\mono\MonoRuntimeProvider.java is unchanged. Skipping.
  Resource obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\Seppuku.java is unchanged. Skipping.
_GeneratePackageManagerJava:
Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CreateBaseApk:
Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CompileJava:
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CompileDex:
Skipping target "_CompileDex" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_BuildApkFastDev:
Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_Mandroid:
Skipping target "_Mandroid" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_Sign:
Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Done Building Project "C:\Trabalho\Temp\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.25

Waiting for device..
Target device is armeabi-v7a..
Installing the Mono shared runtime (armeabi-v7a - 40204)..
Installing the API 15 platform framework..
Removing any previous version..
Copying application to device...
Getting installation path...
Installing assemblies...
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

The Stop:
An error occurred installing the package assemblies.
http://i46.tinypic.com/10pbqma.png

(try to post the img direct but have "no reputation")

Comment: why someone vote -1 on my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug in Mono for Android](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6117), preventing deployment to Jelly Bean hardware. (Deployment to the emulator is reported to still work.)

This will be fixed in the forthcoming 4.2.5 release. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

As a workaround, you can disable use of the shared runtime. (Unfortunately this isn't an option for the evaluation version, and it will also greatly increase deployment time.)

I would instead suggest [using the x86 emulator](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Configuring_the_x86_Emulator) until this bug is fixed, unless you have another (non-Jelly Bean) hardware device to test on.

Comment: Jon, thank u!
I will try to downgrade to 4.2.2 until the next version comes out.